# Routing with Node.js and Express

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am writing my server with Express 4.10.4.
My server need only one route.

http://www.domain.com/a/b/c/d

Only one that I want is a separation between the last element and the others.

So I wrote the code like below.

```
app.get('/*/:last', function (req, res) { ... });
```

It works, but the result contained in req.params is `{ 0: 'd', last: 'a/b/c' }`

My expected result is `{ 0: 'a/b/c', last: 'd' }.`

So how can I achieve this?

Comment: Your expected result isn't a valid object.

Comment: @TimothyStrimple I am sorry. I was my missing. Actually I expected { 0: 'a/b/c', last: 'd' }. But the expression, /*/:last, doesn't not mean it. I read a lout of materials, but I don't know :(

Answer (score 0):

You can't get exactly what you're after (or I don't know how) using the default express router, but you can get close using RegEx.

```
app.get(/.*\/(.*)/, function (req, res) { ... });
```

will give you: `{ 0: 'd' }`